# Emacs Lisp. How handle http response when url is incorrect?

Tags: elisp

I use **url.el** to create http request by **url-retrieve-synchronously**. And when url is correct all is fine. 
Code example:

```
(with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously my-url)
  (hoge--log-debug "\n%s"(buffer-string)))
```

But:

1. How I can handle http response when url is incorrect. 
   e.g. "http://2222httpbin.org/xml" (Unknown host)?
2. How I can get http status response?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `url-retrieve-synchronously` only returns a valid buffer or nil. I don't think you can retrieve the status. Your best option is to call `url-retrieve` which allows you to pass a callback function, where you can access all the details.

#### Workaround

Looking at the processes given by `list-processes`,  it appeared that the background process was still hanging there. Deleting it would call the callback function. So we only need to delete it ourselves when we now the process failed:

```
(defun url-retrieve-please (url callback)
  (apply callback
         (block waiter
           (let ((process
                   (get-buffer-process
                    (url-retrieve url (lambda (&rest args)
                                        (return-from waiter args))))))
             ;; We let a chance for the connection to establish
             ;; properly.  When it succeeds, the callback will return
             ;; from the waiter block.
             ;; When it fails to connect, we exit this loop.
             (loop until (eq 'failed (process-status process))
                   ;; sitting leaves a chance for Emacs to handle
                   ;; asynchronous tasks.
                   do (sit-for 0.1))

             ;; Deleting the process forces the above lambda callback
             ;; to be called, thanks to the process sentinel being in
             ;; place. In the tests, we always exit from the above 
             ;; callback and not after the block normally exits. The
             ;; behaviour seems quite regular, so I don't sleep 
             ;; forever after this command.
             (delete-process process)))))
```

#### Tests

```
(url-retrieve-please "http://yahoo.com" (lambda (&rest args) (message "%S" args)))

"((:redirect \"https://www.yahoo.com/\" :peer (:certificate (:version 3 :serial-number \"1c:25:43:0e:d0:a6:02:e8:cc:3a:97:7b:05:39:cc:e5\" :issuer \"C=US,O=Symantec Corporation,OU=Symantec Trust Network,CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4\" :valid-from \"2015-10-31\" :valid-to \"2017-10-30\" :subject \"C=US,ST=California,L=Sunnyvale,O=Yahoo Inc.,OU=Information Technology,CN=www.yahoo.com\" :public-key-algorithm \"RSA\" :certificate-security-level \"Medium\" :signature-algorithm \"RSA-SHA256\" :public-key-id \"sha1:47:16:26:79:c6:4f:b2:0f:4b:89:ea:28:dc:0c:41:6e:80:7d:59:a9\" :certificate-id \"sha1:41:30:72:f8:03:ce:96:12:10:e9:a4:5d:10:da:14:b0:d2:d4:85:32\") :key-exchange \"ECDHE-RSA\" :protocol \"TLS1.2\" :cipher \"AES-128-GCM\" :mac \"AEAD\")))"

(url-retrieve-please "http://2222httpbin.org/xml" (lambda (&rest args) (message "%S" args)))   

"((:error (error connection-failed \"deleted
\" :host \"2222httpbin.org\" :service 80)))"
```

Comment: Callback function call only when has response from server. But when has error: Unknown host  (no response from server) , as result callback function is not call. How I can handle error "Unknown host"?

Comment: @Alexei I took some time to look at this, and I have a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the status code, use `url-http-symbol-value-in-buffer` on the obtained buffer.

Example:

```
(url-http-symbol-value-in-buffer 'url-http-response-status
                   (url-retrieve-synchronously "http://httpbin.org/get"))
```